# Constructing a HuggingFace Dataset using a custom PyTorch Dataset

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

Hi I am new to using transformers in HuggingFace and trying to train a model using my custom text data. I have my custom dataset ad PyTorch dataset. The text labels are longer than 512 and I add `truncation` and `offset_mapping` to truncate and create new lines in the dataset like so:

```py
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    # ...
    encoding = processor(image, words, 
                         boxes=boxes, word_labels=labels, 
                         truncation=True, padding="max_length", 
                         return_overflowing_tokens=True, 
                         return_offsets_mapping=True)
```

I would like to construct a HuggingFace `Dataset` but when I call `Dataset.from_dict(myPytorchDataset)`, I get:

> 'MyDataset' object has no attribute 'items'

I did try the new `from_generator` method as well like so,
`Dataset.from_generator(myPytorchDataset)`, I get:

> 'MyDataset' object is not callable

I currently do the conversion like so:

```py
from datasets import Dataset, concatenate_datasets

concat_dataset = Dataset.from_dict(myPytorchDataset[0])
for i in range(1,len(myPytorchDataset)):
    d = Dataset.from_dict(myPytorchDataset[i])
    concat_dataset = concatenate_datasets([concat_dataset, d])

###
# Before concat 

# myPytorchDataset[0].keys() -> dict_keys(['input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'bbox', 'labels', 'pixel_values']) 

# sizes for a random sample 
# input_ids torch.Size([6, 512]) 
# attention_mask torch.Size([6, 512]) 
# bbox torch.Size([6, 512, 4]) 
# pixel_values torch.Size([6, 3, 224, 224])
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How does your data look like? Could you share 1-5 data points?

Comment: `myPytorchDataset[0].keys()` -> `dict_keys(['input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'bbox', 'labels', 'pixel_values'])` 

 sizes for a random sample
`input_ids torch.Size([6, 512])
attention_mask torch.Size([6, 512])
bbox torch.Size([6, 512, 4])
pixel_values torch.Size([6, 3, 224, 224])`

`len(myPytorchDataset[0]['input_ids'][0])` -> `512`
`len(myPytorchDataset[0]['input_ids'])` -> `2`

Basically, it is batched and concat is removing the batching

Comment: Put it in the question =)